# jquery flot bar chart doesn't display

Tags: jquery, flot, bar-chart

I want to plot a bar char in real time (the data is updated every one second). My bar chart should plot the previous and the new added data every time there is a new data point appears. I have perviously plotted histogram, scatter plot using flot. They all worked out well. I don't understand why this is not working now.

I don't have any error. When I debug I see that my data is correct.

Sample of my code is

```
 var options = {
            series: {
            bars:{show:true}
    }};

        $(document).ready(function() {

          chart1 = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
          [{
            data:  new_data,
            xaxis: {ticks:8,minTickSize: 1},
            yaxis: {min:-1,max:3,tickSize:1},
            grid: { borderWidth: 1  }
            }],options)

         });
```

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: What data is contained in the `new_data` variable?

Comment: new_data = [[0, 1], [1200, 1], [2400, 0], [3600, 1]]; such kind of data. Every 1 second one data point is added. When debug, alert(new_data) gives 0,1,1200,1,2400,0,...

Comment: You should probably show the code that does the updates.  Also note that xaxis, yaxis and grid, as you've provided them, belong in options, not the data series.

Comment: When properly structured, your code works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/1690/.  Although, that seems like odd data for a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I was storing my data in different format. I was suppose to send `new_data` to plot function like `[[0, 1], [1200, 1], [2400, 0], [3600, 1]];` rather I was sending it like `[0, 1], [1200, 1], [2400, 0], [3600, 1]`.